# Showing a message in the same page after submitting a form

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a simple HTML form with a name & email address field and a submit button.

After filling in the form and submitting it, I want a message such as "Thank you for your response" to appear on the same page.

I'm looking for a easy clean PHP fix for this. I want all the code to stay on one page (Not separate it into two different files).

I've been searching on Google, but they have much more complex situations.

Your help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

EDIT: I want the form to disappear after pressing submit and just show the "Thank you for your response" message. I forgot to mention that. Sorry.

```
<form>
<p><span>Name</span><input class="contact" type="text" name="your_name" value="" /></p>
<p><span>Email Address</span><input class="contact" type="text"
name="your_email" value="" /></p>
<p style="padding-top: 15px"><span>&nbsp;</span><input class="submit"
type="submit" name="contact_submitted" value="submit" /></p>
</form>
```

Comment: I've just searched how to submit form and get a response in the same page on Google. I've been through many sites. This is just for learning purposes. I am not very good with coding, so please be nice.

Answer (score 1):

please try below code.

```
<?php
if($_POST) {
    echo "Thank you for your response";
}
?>
<form name="test" action="" method="post">
<p><span>Name</span><input class="contact" type="text" name="your_name" value="" /></p>
<p><span>Email Address</span><input class="contact" type="text"
name="your_email" value="" /></p>
<p style="padding-top: 15px"><span>&nbsp;</span><input class="submit"
type="submit" name="contact_submitted" value="submit" /></p>
</form>
```

Comment: That works, but I want the form to disappear after pressing submit and just show the "Thank you for your response" message. I forgot to mention that. Sorry.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value. A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Answer (score 1):

Would something like the following help? Essentially, when you hit submit, some special variables are set in the $_POST array, and you can access those. If those variables are set when we're building the page in PHP, then we can do some processing/send an email/show a different response page.

```
<?php
  if (array_key_exists($_POST['your_email'])) /* and other validation */ {
?>
<p>Thanks!</p>
<?php } else { ?>
<form action="POST">
<p><span>Name</span><input class="contact" type="text" name="your_name" value="" /></p>
<p><span>Email Address</span><input class="contact" type="text"
name="your_email" value="" /></p>
<p style="padding-top: 15px"><span>&nbsp;</span><input class="submit"
type="submit" name="contact_submitted" value="submit" /></p>
</form>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

in you form validate page

```
header('location: ../page.php?case=Thank you for your response');
```

in your page

```
<?php print $_GET['case']; ?>
```

Comment: As currently written, this will make your site susceptible to XSS and other content injection attacks.